# laptop hibernates/sleeps/shuts down but immediately wakes up

Tags: windows-10, laptop, hibernate

I have problem with laptop hybernation. Seems like laptop hybernates but immediately something wakes laptop up. Bellow I append command outputs and screenshots of my settings, based on hints which I've found on Internet.

```
C:\Users\wakatana>systeminfo
OS Name:                   Microsoft Windows 10 Home
OS Version:                10.0.19041 N/A Build 19041

C:\WINDOWS\system32>powercfg /devicequery wake_armed
NONE

C:\WINDOWS\system32>powercfg /waketimers
Timer set by [PROCESS] \Device\HarddiskVolume3\Windows\SystemApps\Microsoft.Windows.StartMenuExperienceHost_cw5n1h2txyewy\StartMenuExperienceHost.exe expires at 4:00:00 AM on 倀⬫•.

C:\WINDOWS\system32>powercfg /lastwake
Wake History Count - 1
Wake History [0]
  Wake Source Count - 0
  
C:\WINDOWS\system32>powercfg /L
Existing Power Schemes (* Active)
-----------------------------------
Power Scheme GUID: 381b4222-f694-41f0-9685-ff5bb260df2e  (Balanced)
Power Scheme GUID: 49ef8fc0-bb7f-488e-b6a0-f1fc77ec649b  (Dell) *

PS C:\Users\wakatana> Get-ScheduledTask | ? {$_.Settings.WakeToRun -eq $true}
TaskPath                                       TaskName                          State
--------                                       --------                          -----
\Microsoft\Windows\.NET Framework\             .NET Framework NGEN v4.0.30319... Disabled
\Microsoft\Windows\.NET Framework\             .NET Framework NGEN v4.0.30319... Disabled
\Microsoft\Windows\InstallService\             WakeUpAndContinueUpdates          Disabled
\Microsoft\Windows\InstallService\             WakeUpAndScanForUpdates           Disabled
\Microsoft\Windows\SharedPC\                   Account Cleanup                   Disabled

PS C:\Users\wakatana> Get-ScheduledTask | ? {$_.Settings.WakeToRun -eq $true -and $_.State -ne "Disabled"}
PS C:\Users\wakatana>
```

`C:\Users\wakatana>schtasks` is a bit longer so I've linked it [here](https://pastebin.com/nRCbPhDU)

[image: device manager wireless card]
[image: event viewer Power Troubleshooter]
[image: maintenance]
[image: power_options_balanced]
[image: power_options_dell]
[image: services]
[image: task_scheduler]

**EDIT:** I've realized that same thing happens also when I issue sleep or shutdown. Only possible solution to shutdown laptop was to press power button. After this seems that shutdown, sleep and hibernation are working fine.

Comment: Have you looked in the system event logs?

Comment: Yes, take look at 2nd screenshot. There is Power-Troubleshooter filter enabled